# How to make this Firebase Database use case multi-user safe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Firebase Database to matchmake my simple 2 player mobile game.

The flow that I am trying to follow is

**Assuming there are no other game requests**

1. User selects find a game
2. A limittofirst(1) query is used on the 'lobby' reference
3. Nothing is found
4. Write the user's UID to the lobby using push
5. Wait for the record to be found by another game request

**Assuming there are outstanding game requests**

1. User selects to find a game
2. A limittofirst(1) query is used on the 'lobby' reference of the database
3. A record is found with a UID
4. Delete the record in the lobby
5. Set up a game that contains both players

My question is: if two or more users try and find a game at the same time, it is possible that the limittofirst will return the same UID for multiple people before the record can be deleted. Is there any way to make sure that a UID in the lobby is retrieved only once to be used to set up a game?

I read the docs about transactions and it didn't seem to fit this use case. I don't want the read / write to keep trying until successful. I basically want to read and delete in the same call so that the value can't be used more than once.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. The logic to implement this will be inside of a Firebase Function if that helps with a solution at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can only have two states:

1. There is an outstanding request, and you pair with the user in that request.
2. There is no outstanding request, and you become the outstanding request.

In that case I'd model precisely that in the database:

```
outstanding_requests: "uid"
```

Now you can perform a transaction on this node to read-and-set it in one go. While this transaction will be contentious, it should be pretty short-lived.